# What should I write in standalone.xml to have slf4j?

Tags: xml, maven, logging, wildfly, slf4j

I am developing an app and I must put slf4j logging into my standalone.xml file. I have dependencies in my pom for this but I don't know what should I write in standalone.xml. This is the log part of my standalone.xml:

```
<logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
```

Could anybody say what should I write into this file?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything. slf4j is a logging facade. You only need a dependency on the `org.slf4j:slf4j-api` and it should be marked with `<scope>provided</scope>` in your pom. WildFly will add the slf4j API and an implementation to your deployments class path.